# my decoration sometimes appears just outside the triangle

Tags: python

It seems that my decoration sometimes appears just outside the triangle... How can I fix this?

```
import random
n = int(input('enter n: '))
x = 1
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0:
        count = 0
    else:
        count = random.randint(0, x)
    print(' ' * (n - i), '*' * count, end = '')
    if i == 0:
        print('&', end = '')
    else:
        print('o', end = '')
    print('*' * (x - count - 1))
    x += 2
```

What do I get for value `n` = 10:

```
           &
          ***o
         *o***
        o******
       ******o**
      *********o*
     *************o
    *****o*********
   *************o***
  ******************o
```

Comment: Seems your decoration sometimes appears just outside of the triangle...

Comment: @trincot how can I fix it?

Comment: If you would edit your question and ask specific about that, your question would actually turn from off-topic, to on-topic.

Comment: @trincot I corrected the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random number you generate may return `x` as `randint` *includes* the second value in the set of possible values. So pass `x - 1` to `randint`:

```
count = random.randint(0, x - 1)
```

It is also a pity that you have a check for `i == 0` in your loop. In that case, why not deal with that first case outside of the loop, and start the loop at 1? It will make your code a bit more elegant.

Comment: This is an easy mistake to make, since virtually all other cases of ranges in Python have an EXCLUSIVE endpoint.  This gotcha just something you have to remember.

Comment: Indeed, you can use `randrange` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
def tree(n):
    from random import sample
    body = ["&"] + ["".join(sample("o" + "*" * (k:=x*2+1), k=k)) for x in range(1, n)]
    spaces = [" " * (x-2) for x in range(n, 1, -1)]
    return "\n".join("".join(tpl) for tpl in zip(spaces, body))

print(tree(10))
```

Output:

```
        &
       o**
      ****o
     o******
    *******o*
   ********o**
  *******o*****
 **************o
o****************
```

Answer (score 0):

I love christmas tress! This is my take on the question :-)

```
import random
n = int(input('Enter tree height: '))

print(" " * (n-1) + "&")
for i in range(2, n+1):
    decoration = random.randint(1, (i-1)*2 -1)
    print(" " * (n - i) + "*" * decoration + "o" + "*" * ((i-1)*2 - decoration))


Enter tree height: 12
           &
          *o*
         **o**
        *o*****
       *o*******
      ********o**
     *******o*****
    ***********o***
   ********o********
  ****************o**
 ***o*****************
*********o*************
```